# Android recyclerView - how to know what section i am in?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am designing an app about different ways to travel. so i have  a data Source in android that has a list of many different categories of businesses. Categories are automobiles, bikes, and airplanes. So imagine a list that has a section of many automobiles, followed by many bikes, followed by many airplanes.  i want to section these out using recyclerView.  But i am not sure how to create the sections/categories ?

i have a model (data source) that i am able to call to get each category like this:
model.getAirplanesList();
model.getCarsList();
model.getBikesList();

Would it be better to have 3 different Models ?  so i need the final product to show first:

```
   1. list of airplanes   
   2. then a list of cars
   3. last a list of bikes
```

i need it to have headers for each section. How can i know which section i am in ?

The 3 categories will use the same layout file so the viewType can remain the same i assume:

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.transports_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

//should i be utilizing viewType somehow ?

and in the onBindViewHolder i am confused how i can know which section i am in. so far i  have it working only for airplanes:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Transport transport = model.get(position).getAirplanesList();
        holder.title.setText(transport.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(transport.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(transport.getYear());

//what about Cars and bikes. how to know what section i am in ?
    }
```

i want my data to be ordered by category/section like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) to group your data into sections.

First create a Section class:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<Transport> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<Transport> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.transports_list_row);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        Transport transport = list.get(position);
        itemHolder.title.setText(transport.getTitle());
        itemHolder.genre.setText(transport.getGenre());
        itemHolder.year.setText(transport.getYear());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Airplanes", model.getAirplanesList()));
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Cars", model.getCarsList()));
sectionAdapter.addSection(new MySection("Bikes", model.getBikesList()));

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track, you can utilize `getItemViewType()` to find the type of `ViewHolder` should be created and populated in the next method, based on object type or constraint. This means that you can have separate models or just have one model and apply constraints (be careful, this should not be heavy operation) to return correct view type.

Simple check the type by constraint:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
   TransporationModel transportation = mList.get(position);
   if(transporation.isBike()){ return VIEW_TYPE_BIKE;
   else if(transporation.isBus()){ return VIEW_TYPE_BUSE;
  //..etc

}
```

Comment: Ok. But how do i group them?

Comment: If you have different models, let them implement common interface under which you pass homogeneous list of objects to the adapter, like `List<Transporable>>`, all `BusTransporationModel`, `BikeTransporationModel` implement this interface, so you can group them in same list without making it of type `List<Object>>`.

Comment: i have only one model.  The model is called businesses. inside businesses i have airplaneList, bikeList and carList. could you recommend how i can do this given this way ? could you start me off with code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be help you.
In Adapter getView method do like this

```
  @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        final Item i = items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if (i.isSection()) {

                SectionItem si = (SectionItem) i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
                    v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);

                 TextView sectionView = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());


            } else if (i.isItem()) {

                Exam exam = (Exam) i;
                 v = vi.inflate(R.layout.exampanel, null);

                TextView examtopic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.topic_title);
                TextView examcontent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listcontent);
                TextView datetimetext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datetime);
                TextView colortext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.color_text);                       

            }

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: How does this keep them ordered by category ? What you have done is added the section names. But the data within the sections is not ordered per category. it is all over the place. am i wrong ? What i want is something ordered. i want a list of cars, a list of airplanes and a list of bikes all placed in the correct category. It is like a 3 separate lists but all with the same recyclerview if possible.

Comment: I think i see what your hinting at. I should just keep all the data in one list but separate it by sections.  Right now i have 3 lists in 1 models  but i assuming you mean it would be better to have 1 list and just place sections like "#" in the arraylist to designate a section.

Comment: You just add that 3 list in a single list and pass that list to custom adapter. So every list having separate module class. Then Segregate that list in custom adapter by module classes.

Comment: that way i still would not know where the sections begin. imagine i have a arrayList container with my 3 lists inside.  How to know in getView when a new section is encountered ? can you show a demo in code perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The greatest library i found for multiple sections is [EPOXY](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) by airbnb.  Makes it so easy.  solved my issues.

Comment: I have issues getting the the classes that get generated at the build to work. The classes with _ post fix  are not getting generated. Can you provide some guidelines?

Comment: i have not used it in a while, so forgot the details sorry .. https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/epoxy-airbnbs-view-architecture-on-android-c3e1af150394